# tkinter Label overlap (.place(),.pack())

Tags: python, tkinter, button, label, overlap

```
def func(list,n):
    if n==1:
        text=round(kcal_measure(sport.get(),now[0],time.get()),1)
        list.append(text)
        Label(newWindow,text=sport.get()+"KCAL: "+str(text)+"kcal").place(x=60,y=132)
        time.delete(0,END)
    if n==2:
        Label(newWindow,text="Total KCAL: "+str(sum(list))+"kcal").pack()

Button(newWindow,text="add",command=lambda:func(k,1)).place(x=105,y=105)
Button(newWindow,text="ok",command=lambda:func(k,2)).place(x=155,y=105)
```

[.place() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc1EC.jpg)

```
def func(list,n):
    if n==1:
        text=round(kcal_measure(sport.get(),now[0],time.get()),1)
        list.append(text)
        Label(newWindow,text=sport.get()+"KCAL: "+str(text)+"kcal").pack()
        time.delete(0,END)
    if n==2:
        Label(newWindow,text="Total KCAL: "+str(sum(list))+"kcal").pack()

Button(newWindow,text="add",command=lambda:func(k,1)).place(x=105,y=105)
Button(newWindow,text="ok",command=lambda:func(k,2)).place(x=155,y=105)
```

[.pack() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAJKk.jpg)

I want the label not to overlap with the button.
First, I use .place(). But this method overlap between labels.
Next, I use .pack(). But this method does not overlap between labels, but overlaps with buttons.

How can I place labels and buttons neatly?

Comment: You shouldn't use both `.pack` and `.place` in the same frame/window. Stick to only one of them. I prefer using `.pack`

Comment: @TheLizzard However, when using `.pack`, buttons are not placed on both sides and are placed up and down.

Comment: You know that you can pass in a `side=...` parameter where that parameter can be one of: `"top"`, `"bottom"`, `"left"`, `"right"`

Comment: @hyem_msg You can put the buttons in a frame. Then you can use `.pack()` on all the widgets in your case.

Comment: @acw1668 I could this problem using the frame. Thank you.

Comment: @TheLizzard: it's perfectly fine to use `pack` and `place` together, since `place` doesn't affect any other widgets. It's `grid` and `pack` that can't be mixed with widgets that share the same parent.

Comment: @BryanOakley From best practises it is usually a good idea to use only one of them. Otherwise it can be very difficult to control them, especially when their parent is resized.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I disagree. While it's a best practice as a general rule to not use `place`, it really is quite common to use it in addition to other geometry managers in those rare times when `place` is the best tool for the job. `place` won't interfere with other widgets when the parent is resized. The problem with mixing `grid` and `pack` is that they each try to control the parent, but `place` does not.

Comment: @BryanOakley I know about the `.grid`/`.pack` problem (and it raises an error for me - python 3.7). I haven't ever had to use `.place`. I always suggest people to stick with `.grid`/`.pack`.

Comment: @TheLizzard: yes, it's good advice to stick to `grid` and `pack`. However, your earlier comment said you shouldn't mix `pack` and `place` which is misleading There's no harm in mixing `place` with either `grid` or `pack` -- they don't interfere with each other.  In every case where I've used `place`, I've had no choice but to mix it with `pack` or `grid`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I used the word *shouldn't* and not *can't* for that reason. Next time I will try to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to not use `place` at all in this case. While `place` is good for some uses, it's not generally the right tool.

In your case I recommend creating a frame to hold the buttons, and then use `pack` to add that frame below the other widgets. Then, you can put the buttons inside that frame however you want.

Comment: I solve this problem using the frame. I should refrain from using `.place()` from now on. Thanks for your advice!